# Can there still be SQL injection when storing the password as a hash?

Tags: php, sql-injection, bcrypt, algorithm

Could there be any SQL injection vulnerability in the code below since it only queries the database for username and bcrypt hash?

Would the vulnerability of this code be more on the bcrypt hashing algorithm, SQL injection or both?

Also can anybody give me some tips on how to sanitize code  and explain how bcrypt's algorithm works?

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>password validation</title></head>
    <body>


    <fieldset>
    <legend>enter password</legend>
    <form action =passval.php method = "post">
    <table>
     <tr>
    <td>Email:</td><td><input type="id" name ="id" /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password:</td><td><input type = "password" name="password" />         <br /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value ="insert" />
       </form>
         </fieldset>
         <br />


         <?php
     // connect to the server

      $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'social');

      // check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit("connection failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
     } else {
      echo "connection established";
      }




        if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['id'])) {
         $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
      $id =($_POST["id"]);
      echo $pass;
    //$hash = $bcrypt->hash($pass['password']);
    $bcrypt = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
      $input = $pass;
      $query = "SELECT pass FROM social WHERE   email = '$id'";
       $result = $conn->query($query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    //echo $row['pass'];
    //echo "<br />";
    echo "success";

   if (password_verify($input, $row['pass'])) {
    echo "matching pass" . header("Location: inserh.php");
   } else{
    echo "not a  mathch";
    }
    }
    }

    $conn->close();         // close the connection
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. Please format it properly.

Comment: A root database login is also considered bad. Make specific logins that are only granted the minimum of rights they need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Is this SQL injection?

Yes.

### Why?

Let's look at what's happening here.

```
$query = "SELECT pass FROM social WHERE   email = '$id'";
```

This passes `$id` directly to the query. If `$id` is not sanitized, SQL injection will occur.

```
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['id'])) {
     $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
  $id =($_POST["id"]);
  echo $pass;
```

So we see here that `$id` is not sanitized when it is assigned the value of the user-supplied email address. When this `$id` is passed in to the query, the attacker can inject on the query.

### Are there any other vulnerabilities?

Actually, the concern isn't bcrypt, but how users create passwords and interact with bcrypt. Ensure that you limit the size of passwords to 4096. Additional details [here](http://symfony.com/blog/security-releases-cve-2013-5958-symfony-2-0-25-2-1-13-2-2-9-and-2-3-6-released).

Secondly, currently, users can execute XSS:

```
echo $pass;
```

While this is intended for debugging purposes, take care to not leave debugging statements when you are ready to deploy your code.

### Okay, but how do I fix this?

Parameterized queries.

If this is a brand new project, I would recommend using an ORM like Doctrine. It will automatically do parameterized queries for you. If that doesn't work for your needs, at minimum use PDO, which supports parameterized queries instead of `mysqli` which does not. You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

For more general information, OWASP is a good place to go for web application vulnerabilities: [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: `mysqli` does support [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), `mysql_*` doesn't. It's also worth noting that PDO might go for "emulated" prepared statements so it's best to specify you want "real" prepared statements. Otherwise some really [obscure edge cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602) might haunt you. Not sure why you have recommended a size limit of 4096 while [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) says it will truncate the password to **72** characters using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`.